# Unreadable messages on RStudio on Windows

Tags: r, windows, character-encoding, rstudio

I am using RStudio as frontend to R. It works perfectly on GNU/Linux (even with russian locale and russian messages). Hoewever, on Windows it works worse.
The problem is with fonts or charsets of messages.

I installed RStudio Version 0.99.467 (AMD64) and R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18).

I see the following prompt at the beginning (no issues with that, locale is en_US, english language):

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) -- "World-Famous Astronaut"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

But when I try to do wrong thing, suppose trying to load package which is not installed, I see unreadable error message.

```
> library(abcdef)
Error in library(abcdef) : íåò ïàêåòà ïîä íàçâàíèåì ‘abcdef’
```

How to make it readable?

By the way, this problem appears **only** in RStudio. RGui works fine (even with russian messages, no suspicious letters):

```
> library(abcdef)
Ошибка в library(abcdef) :нет пакета под названием ‘abcdef’
```

(package "abcdef" is not installed).

Not sure where to start digging. Is it even resolvable? Or is it a bug in RStudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't have non-Unicode russian charset (1251) on your system.

Ensure that locale is set to Russian in Control panel > Regional > Administrative > Change system locale, then restart your system and check if problem persists.

OR you can switch R language to English by adding `language = EN` to `RConsole` file in R's `\etc\` directory (`C:\Program Files\R\R-x.x.x\etc\` by default).

Comment: Do you have any idea how to set it locally for application (not for all system) ?

By the way - it's not helping. It's "English (United States)" locale there.

Comment: What `Sys.getlocale()` is giving you? Maybe it's best to switch the language to english, added it to answer.

Comment: It gives me [1] "LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251"

Yes, it's russian - but I have no idea why. It's only inside RStudio. If I open CMD and type systeminfo, I see 

System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)

Comment: By the way, I want to see english messages only. That's why I set english locale globally (I use russian locale only for things like date format or money separator...)

Comment: Then you can set language to English manually in RConsole file.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark as an answer so other users can see it.

Comment: Sure. But I still think there is a better options how to make it working on any UTF-8 comptabile language... Will write it here if find out something.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue.

All my comments of code was changes to:

```
# Р—Р°РіСЂСѓР·РёРј Р±РёР±Р»РёРѕС‚РµРєРё: ####
library(googlesheets4)
```

First, I used

```
Sys.setlocale(locale = "English")
```

and it didn't help.

Then, the solve was to change only one thing in code. Just add '.UTF-8':

```
Sys.setlocale(locale = "English.UTF-8")
```